# Angular: Revert object back to original if update fails

Tags: angular

I have a `client` object that gets updated through an inline form and if my service cannot successfully update the client, I want it to revert to what it was before the before the client side changes took place.  Here's what I have so far:

```
  updateForm() {
    let client_id = this.client.id
    let curr_client = this.client
    console.log("updating", curr_client)

    this.clientService.update(this.client, "client", this.token).subscribe(
      data => {
        // sets this client to new client returned from service
        this.client = data
        this.clientService.handleResponse("Successfully updated the client!")
        this.clientService.setClient(this.client)
      },
      err => {
        console.log(curr_client)
        this.clientService.handleResponse("Ut oh.. couldn't update the client!")
        // attempt at reverting back but curr_client changes with this.client
        this.client = curr_client
      },
      () => this.editMode = false
    )
  }
```

What can I change in the failure block to revert the client?

Comment: Clone the object and set it to needed variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I did:

```
private currentProduct: IProduct;
private originalProduct: IProduct;

get product(): IProduct {
    return this.currentProduct;
}
set product(value: IProduct) {
    this.currentProduct = value;
    // Clone the object to retain a copy
    this.originalProduct = Object.assign({}, value);
}
```

I clone the object to make a copy as soon as the product is set from the Http call. Then I can use the original if I need to revert back.